# I want to set azure server side encryption to file present in azure blob container

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

The problem is I want to set azure server side encryption to file which is present in azure blob container but i do not found any way to set server side encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are 2 sides to this:

1. [Azure Storage is encrypted by default](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-default-encryption-for-azure-blobs-files-table-and-queue-storage/) at rest
2. You can use [Azure Storage Service Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption) to encrypt data. You can use REST API\powershell\cli\SDK to do that.

Notice that you would need to [rewrite your existing data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption#frequently-asked-questions-about-storage-service-encryption-for-data-at-rest) on the storage to the storage to encrypt it.

Comment: does there any java API which allows me to set encryption to file which i am trying to upload into azure blob container. the solution you maintained will provide encryption to storage account but i want to set encryption to individual files. @4c74356b41

Comment: no, there is no way of achiving this. encrypt file before upload. only way

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption) (emphasis mine):

> Existing Data - SSE only encrypts newly created data after the encryption is enabled. If for example you create a new Resource Manager storage account but don't turn on encryption, and then you upload blobs or archived VHDs to that storage account and then turn on SSE, those blobs **will not be encrypted unless they are rewritten or copied**.

So only data written after you enable SSE gets encrypted. You will need to do as they say and rewrite/copy the files.